# ¿Como puedo verificar un dato de tipo String en java?

Tags: java, java-7

Estoy aprendiendo java y estaba haciendo un programa que recibe el nombre del usuario y si es igual a "Miguel", entonces dira "Perfecto, te encuentras en la base de datos" pero por alguna razon solo ejecuta la exepcion apesar de que el dato ingresado por el usuario sea igual a "Miguel", me gustaria que alguien me guiara.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Switch {

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input_user = input.nextLine();



        if (input_user == "Miguel") {
            System.out.println("Perfecto, te encuentras en la base de datos");
        }else {
            System.out.println("Lo siento, no puede pasar");
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: A que te refieres con que solo ejecuta la excepción, en programación excepción tiene un significado específico y en tu código no veo ninguna excepción, te refieres a que de la condición se ejecuta la parte del else?

Comment: Si exacto perdon

Comment: El operador `==` compara referencias de objetos (por esa razon la condicion siempre dará `false`, puesto cada objeto tiene asignada su propia referencia). Si quieres comparar el contenido del objeto, deberás usar el método [equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object))..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Utiliza `input_User.equals("Miguel")` para los Strings.
Un saludo.

```
 if (input_user.equals("Miguel")) {
        System.out.println("Perfecto, te encuentras en la base de datos");
    }else {
        System.out.println("Lo siento, no puede pasar");
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por su colaboracion, pero me da error cuando utilizo el metodo Equals, 'Switch.java14: error: cannot find symbol; if (input_user.Equals("Miguel")) {; simbol: method Equals(String); location: variable input_user of type String; 1 error'

Comment: Prubea con el Equals en minusculas, sé que parece una tonteria pero Java... es muy de estas cosas, un saludo.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, ya funciona a la perfeccion

Comment: Hola, y porqué no funciona con == cual es la diferencia, me podrías explicar cypher

Comment: @Japv la diferencia seria:

El operador == realiza la comparación a nivel de objeto. Es decir, determina si ambos objetos son iguales.

El método equals() compara los caracteres dentro del objeto String.

Un saludo.

Comment: A ya tienes mi voto positivo, gracias por la explicacion